# Algorithm to center a word in a UILabel

Tags: iphone, ios, algorithm, uilabel

I need to center a word in a UILabel in an iphone app. I have a string of text that is too long to fit in the label, so I would like to make the label center on a specific word and truncate the ends. For example: Here is a sample sentence. "Hi all, I am stuck trying to center a word from a long sentence in a UILabel." I would like to center on the word "stuck" so that the UILabel looks something like this, ". . .I am **stuck** trying to. . .". I found a link to a question that had the same question, but I couldn't get the answer to work for me. I am very new to this kind of programming so any further help would be GREATLY appreciated! Thanks in advance. Here is the link to the other question: [iOS: Algorithm to center a word in a sentence inside of a UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6949195/1243744)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just coded and ran this (but didn't test any edge cases).  The idea is to make an NSRange around the word to be centered, then grow that range symmetrically in each direction, all the while testing the pixel width of the truncated string against the width of the label.

```
- (void)centerTextInLabel:(UILabel *)label aroundWord:(NSString *)word inString:(NSString *)string {

    // do nothing if the word isn't in the string
    //
    NSRange truncatedRange = [string rangeOfString:word];
    if (truncatedRange.location == NSNotFound) {
        return;
    }

    NSString *truncatedString = [string substringWithRange:truncatedRange];

    // grow the size of the truncated range symmetrically around the word
    // stop when the truncated string length (plus ellipses ... on either end) is wider than the label
    // or stop when we run off either edge of the string
    //
    CGSize size = [truncatedString sizeWithFont:label.font];
    CGSize ellipsesSize = [@"......" sizeWithFont:label.font];  // three dots on each side
    CGFloat maxWidth = label.bounds.size.width - ellipsesSize.width;

    while (truncatedRange.location != 0 &&
           truncatedRange.location + truncatedRange.length + 1 < string.length &&
           size.width < maxWidth) {

        truncatedRange.location -= 1;
        truncatedRange.length += 2;  // move the length by 2 because we backed up the loc
        truncatedString = [string substringWithRange:truncatedRange];
        size = [truncatedString sizeWithFont:label.font];
    }

    NSString *ellipticalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"...%@...", truncatedString];
    label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;  // this can go someplace else
    label.text = ellipticalString;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
[self centerTextInLabel:self.label aroundWord:@"good" inString:@"Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country"];
```

If you think it's a keeper, you could change it into a category method on UILabel.

Comment: I must say, it's a great start.

Comment: Excellent, but won't the `while` loop extend the string until it _exceeds_ the width of the label, then use that slightly-too-long string?  Would it be better to cache the longest known string that was still shorter than the label?  It may still appear to work because `UILabel` can slightly shrink its content to keep it all in view, but that seems unreliable.  Or maybe the label decides it is too long, cuts of the ellipsis, and then adds its own...

Comment: Yeah - edgy cases.  Could reduce the maxWidth threshold a bit.  Not sure if the questioner is okay with a 1pt font autoresize.  Another problem: in a variable width font,  we might enlarge the range to surround chars on each size of different widths.  Here again, we should get a good fit, but not pixel-perfect.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I won't get to it until later tonight to try this out, but it looks like it will work. Thanks again. I will let everyone know how it works.

Comment: By the way, this aswer solved my problem! Great job @danh! Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: use **two** labels, one left aligned and one right aligned. Both should be truncated at the outside of the "outer" (visible) label border, and placed side by side.  Distribute your sentence that your center word constitutes the transit between both.

In this way, you won't get a perfect centering (it will vary with the length of your center word) but it will be close to it.

Comment: The the word that I want to be visible may be at various places in the sentence. My text string is loaded from an variable strings so it could be a different size every time.

Comment: @infobug Both fact does not matter. Load the sentenct, split it at the center word, and put both strings in the different labels - volia. However, danh's solution is more elegant (but of course more elaborate).